# jQuery Countdown plugin not working with Ace Editor

Tags: jquery, ace-editor

I have a jQuery countdown plugin on my page and it works fine on all browsers.

```
$('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: 300 , format: 'dHMS'});
```

But when I include the ace editor javascript, the countdown just shows `NaN` for everything on IE, although it still works fine on other browsers.

When I include this:

```
<script src="js/jquery.countdown.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="js/ace/src/ace.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

the jQuery countdown plugin does not work on IE 8.

If I comment out the `ace.js` javascript, it again works on all browsers, including IE.

Comment: The ace.js code can be found here: https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/master/build/src/ace.js

Answer (score 1):

Try using jQuery in no conflict mode:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: 300 , format: 'dHMS'});
```